# mongodb reindex the collection not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have designed my Schema to have a unique field as .

```
var bookingSchema = new Schema({
booking_id_customer: {
    type: Number,
    index: { unique: true }

}
```

}

Due to some changes I am removing the index, my new design looks like.

```
 var bookingSchema = new Schema({
    booking_id_customer: {
        type: Number

    }
}
```

But still I get the **duplicate key error index** message from mongodb.When I provide duplicate bookingId.
I tried the reIndex() method.

```
     var bookingSchema = new Schema({
        booking_id_customer: {
            type: Number

        }
    }
bookingSchema.reIndex();
```

But I get booking.reIndex is not a function error.
My mongoDb is hosted in mlabs.
How to overcome this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Does not work like that. Your schema definitions have no record of the current state of indexes already in the database. You need to remove the index yourself. Best done in the mongo shell. Mongoose will attempt to create indexes on startup so you may as well drop them all. Go into the shell  and do a `db.bookings.dropIndexes()` , presuming the collection is actually called "bookings", which should be the default name if you called the model `Booking`.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks a lot it worked .

Answer (score 2):

First you need to drop your indexes then reindex the fields when this is finished, so do (ShopModel here is a reference to my collection or model ShopModel sometimes referred to as db.whateverYourCollectionNameIs):

```
const ShopModel = require('./shop_model');

ShopModel.collection.dropIndexes(function(){
    ShopModel.collection.reIndex(function(finished){
            console.log("finished re indexing")
     })
})
```

To check your indexes have worked you can run:

```
ShopModel.collection.getIndexes({full: true}).then(indexes => {
    console.log("indexes:", indexes);
}).catch(console.error);
```